# $\pi(x.y) \ge \pi(x).\pi(y)$ holds for $x, y \ge 8$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I am looking for a proof, or a reference, or a remark or a comment with the conjecture as follows:

Let $\pi(x)$ is [Prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) of $x$. For $x$, $y$ be two positive integer numbers for $x, y \ge 8$ then

> $$\pi(x.y) \ge \pi(x).\pi(y)$$

Noted: I compute the conjecture is true with $8 \le x, y \le 10^9$

PS: This conjecture inspired from [Second Hardy–Littlewood conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture), for $x, y \ge 2$ then

$$\pi(x+y) \le \pi(x)+\pi(y)$$

Comment: this follows from the inequalities $A x/\log x<\pi(x)<Bx/\log x$, $x>x_0$ with $A,B,x_0$ fixed of order unity. see for example [D. Burde](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_23_cheby_error.pdf) (2006).

Comment: This is a consequence of the prime number theorem for large x and y.   It might be of interest to determine precisely for which pairs of x and y this does not hold.  Gerhard "For Unconditional Results Use Dusart" Paseman, 2018.06.26.

Comment: Thank You very much, this is not conjecture, this is Exercise @GerhardPaseman

Comment: Many thank to dear @CarloBeenakker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an answer to the exercise.  Let us take $x$ and $y$ sufficiently large, and take  constants $A$ and $B$ so that we can apply $At \lt \pi(t)\log t \lt Bt$.  Then using these and rewriting the conjectured inequality, we will have it once we can show $$xy\log x \log y \gt (B^2/A)xy\log (xy)$$.  Taking generous values of $B=1.3$ and $A=0.9$, and letting $s=\log x$ and $t=\log y$, we get the above if we have $st \gt 1.9 (s+t)$ which in turn is implied by $(s-2)(t-2) \gt 4$.  So we have the result when both $x$ and $y$ are greater than $55 \gt e^4$.  To bring this down, you can tighten the inequalities above, or examine the roughly 1200 cases when $55 \geq x \geq y \geq 8$.  Using equivalence classes induced by $\pi()$ can reduce the case checking to less than 80 cases.

Gerhard "Done Waiting At The Hospital" Paseman, 2018.06.26.

Comment: Thank You very much. I have a question, I want ask you. Is there proof [Second Hardy–Littlewood conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture) similarly? If there is not similar proof, why not?

Comment: Briefly, because it is expected to be false, because the inequality required is stronger (addition versus addition instead of multiplication versus addition), and because the pi function is rather irregular to expect fine notions of complexity to hold, or be easily proved.  Gerhard " Long Version Won't Fit Here" Paseman, 2018.06.26.

Comment: Let $n$, $m$ be two positive integer numbers, $P_n$ be prime $n-th$. How I can prove that $P_{n+m} \ge P_n+P_m$, or reference for this problem? May You help me?

Comment: How do you know that $0.9t<\pi(t)\log t<1.3t$  for all  $t>55$?